# Between outgoing and incoming clip how do I keep the audio track cutting point as-is but only move the cutting point of the video track?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro

1. What is the name of this operation(s) in general non-linear video editing?
2. How to do it in Apple Final Cut Pro?

[image: Cutting types of outgoing and incoming clip regarding video and audio track]

[image: Complimentary to L-cut and J-cut]

### Note:

- I'm aware that the outcome is a J-cut or an L-cut.
- But when considering the clip boundary on the timeline as the starting point ("before") and keeping the audio cutting point fixed on that reference line and instead moving the video cutting point, the outcome of the part I grabbed is a "┐" shape or "┌" shape.
- Indirectly of course for a "┐" shape you achieved an L-shape to the left and for a "┌" shape a J-shape to the right.
- But seeing it from the video track you grab you achieve an "┐" shape or "┌" shape.

### Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Roll Edit** is the operation to move the edit point between two clips on the timeline.

**In Final Cut Pro** by default this operation affects both the video and the audio portion of a clip.

In order to perform a roll edit only on the video portion of a clip you:

1. Select both clips on the timeline.
2. Expand audio — <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> — or in the context menu
   Now video and audio portion are shown separately on the main timeline
3. Switch to the Trim tool — <kbd>T</kbd> — or click on the dropdown menu top left above the timeline.
4. Now move the edit point between the video clips or audio clips freely.

[image: Final Cut Pro - Roll edit between two clips for audio and video portion separately with keyboard shortcuts]

Long video with more explanation and explicitly shown tool menu and context menu:

[▶️ Final Cut Pro - Roll edit between two clips for audio and video portion together or separately](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wtxgk3pu64rrkq?raw=1)